# Eclipse : using C coding style for new extensions

Tags: eclipse, coding-style

I have an Eclipse project with special  files extension `.m4` which are but `C` files. how can I open them on Eclipse but using C code style just like choosing langage in notepad ++ ?.

Comment: If using Eclipse CDT (_Eclipse for C/C++ developer_), in _Window > Preferences: C/C++ > File Types_ click _New..._ enter `*.m4` as pattern and choose _C Source File_ as type. Or are you just looking for a code highlighter plug-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using Eclipse CDT (*Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers*):

1. In ***Window > Preferences: C/C++ > File Types*** click ***New...***
2. In the C/C++ File Type dialog enter **`*.m4`** as pattern and choose ***C Source File*** as type
3. Click ***OK*** and ***Apply and Close*** to close both dialogs